# strange behavior of templated type

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, int = 0>
struct test {
    typedef char type[3];
};

template<int N>
struct test<long *, N> {
    typedef char type[7];
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof( test<int*>::type ) << std::endl; // 3
    std::cout << sizeof( test<long*>::type ) << std::endl; // 7
    return 0;
}
```

I expected `sizeof( test<long*>::type ) == 3`. Why it is 7?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is you specialized the template, saying that whenever the type argument is `long*`, you should use the second form of the template.  For other arguments, it will use the initial form of the template (with size 3).

Comment: You set it up whenever the type argument is `long*` since the `template <int N > struct test<long *, N>` no longer allows for variable type.

If you wanted to specialize whenever N is non-zero, that can be done as well (though you'll find it easier to have the base be the non-zero case and then have zero specialized)

Comment: Does the default value for `N` get inherited from the generic form?

Comment: Yes. When you declare `test<X>` (without the integer argument), the compiler substitutes `test<X,0>` prior to performing specialization.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that.  My intuition said that shouldn't have compiled at all, so thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You specialized your template so that if the type argument is `long*` then the size is changed. I'm fairly sure you can't mix the `test<int*>` and `test<123>` forms that you want to use (what would the meaning be of a parameter that could be either a type OR a value?). The best you can do is something like:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, int = 0>
struct test {
    typedef char type[3];
};

template<int N>
struct test<int, N> {
    typedef char type[7];
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof( test<int*>::type ) << std::endl; // 3
    std::cout << sizeof( test<long*>::type ) << std::endl; // 3
    std::cout << sizeof( test<int, 123>::type ) << std::endl; // 7
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe if you tell us the real problem you're trying to solve that would help.